# How can I medicate my big, strong cat when I can't get down on the floor?

Tags: cats, medicines

Stardust hiding in the closet. 18 pounds, 14 years old, very strong. I am 71 and have bad knees. I know what to do to give her pills and liquids but can't get down  on the floor without pain. She keeps getting away from me.  I live alone so I have to figure this out for the next two weeks. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use treats or a food it likes to come to you, and when you catch it don't let it go.

Comment: Can you lift your cat onto a table or countertop? I'll write more details if that's something you're able to do.

Comment: There are veterinary technicians that can come to your home to help pill your cat if need be. You would have to call around.

Comment: I found this video extremely helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBSxnNkkd2o.  You don't have to get down on the floor.

Answer (score 6):

Day 1: Give her a small treat on surface that's at a convenient height for you to pill her (e.g., a shelf on a cat tree) -- but don't pill her yet. Do this a few times until she is relaxed about the whole thing. Then give the treat, pill her, and give her another treat.

Subsequent days: Give the treat, pill her, and give her another treat.

This should help in a couple of ways. The routine of treat-pill-treat lets her know what's about to happen. Even if the animal doesn't particularly like what you're about to do, that's less frightening than the unknown. The initial treat will make her come to you, and anticipation of the final treat will help calm her while you administer the pill.

Answer (score 4):

If the pill can be crushed (you need to ask the vet about this) you can mix it in wet food and give it to your cat.

The way to crush pills is to take two spoons and put the pill between them. To avoid wasting medicine, do this inside a small plastic bag and press the spoons together to crush the pill. You might need to do this more than once to crush it all.

If it is a capsule, you open it inside a plastic bag and put the powder on your cat's food.

It is best to use a type of wet food with a strong smell/taste: tuna, calf
or turkey.
Please don't feed your cat for some time before you try this method, as it probably needs to be hungry to eat it.

Comment: some types of medication for cats do contain meat taste and this can make it easier to make your eat it.